# How to run migrations for a specific tenant/schema in Django multi-tenant framework?

Tags: python-3.x, django, multi-tenant, django-migrations, django-tenants

The tenant_command was not working properly according to my requirements.
So, I found out this solution after tweaking the command below

```
python3 manage.py tenant_command migrate --schema=schema_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a migration for a specific tenant we just need to specify schema_name for the tenant after the command migrate like --schema=schemaname

```
python3 manage.py migrate --schema=schema_name
```